# Meaning of adverb followed by まで

Tags: grammar, particle-まで

> 専門家などは、このミサイルはアメリカに届く**ぐらい遠くまで**飛ぶと考えています。
>   Experts think that this missile will fly *far enough to reach* America.

I've never seen まで used with an adverb before. This translation is my best guess. Extrapolating from my guess I made this sentence:

> レースに勝つぐらい速くまで走る。
>   I will run fast enough to win the race.

Is this a natural sentence and does it mean what I think it means? Would this construction be used in everyday speech? If not, how would I express the same idea?

Comment: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/27286/5010

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> 「専門家{せんもんか}などは、このミサイルはアメリカに届{とど}くぐらい遠{とお}く**まで**飛{と}ぶと考{かんが}えています。」
>
> Experts think that this missile will fly far enough to reach America.

Your translation is just plain good here if not literal.

It is, however, incorrect to translate:

> I will run fast enough to win the race.

to

> 「レースに勝{か}つぐらい速{はや}く**まで**走{はし}る。」

The use of 「まで」 is incorrect here.

「まで」 can only describe a ***physical distance*** when combined with 「遠く」 and followed by a verb like 「走る」, but this sentence is all about a ***velocity*** and not about a distance.

Thus, the correct way to say this would be:

> 「レースに勝つ(or 勝てる)ぐらい速く走る。」

Using 「勝てる」 would be slightly more natural.

Finally, you stated:

> "I've never seen まで used with an adverb before. "

「遠く」 here is a ***noun*** meaning 「遠いところ」.

https://kotobank.jp/word/%E9%81%A0%E3%81%8F-581820#E3.83.87.E3.82.B8.E3.82.BF.E3.83.AB.E5.A4.A7.E8.BE.9E.E6.B3.89

「名{めい}」 is short for 「名詞{めいし}」, which means a "noun".